# Overhang detection shader - how to return the coordinates of the vertices?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, webgl2

I'm trying to write a support generation app in browser using three.js, I have tried many approaches and all of them were slow, so now I decided to make the shader compute the overhang position and my program build supports to those points.

The overhang detection shader outputs:
[image: overhang detection]

Now the problem is I cannot figure out how to return those areas in red to the CPU /main JavaScript app to generate simple supports to those points,
I read somewhere here about a GPU CPU approach involving a FBO but can't understand this, is there any way to get the red areas coordinates back to CPU?

I could also calculate this in the vertex shader to update the position of non overhang vertices to be 0,0,0, but the problem is that the vertex position in three JavaScript doesn't update in that way, if there is some way to get updated vertex positions after vertex shader execution it could be a solution.

Maybe transform feedback? How can I use transform feedback from three.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just get the rendered image (like the one you've linked in the question), you can use THREE's wrapper around `readPixels` [readRenderTargetPixels](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels). That will give you values of pixels of the image as an array, you can iterate over it and find red areas. Also, since it seems that your fragment shader does pretty much binary decision (black or red), you can use other channels to store additional information, e.g. in vertex shader:

```
// ...
varying vec3 position;
// ...
void main(void) {
    // ...
    position = gl_Position.xyz / gl_Position.w;
}
```

And in fragment shader:

```
// ...
varying highp vec3 position;
// ...
void main(void) {
    // ...
    gl_FragColor.xyz = 0.5 * (position + 1.0); // position'll be in (-1, 1) range, where as gl_FragColor's clamped to (0, 1)
    gl_FragColor.w = isOverhang ? 1.0 : 0.0;
}
```

Then in JS code:

```
// ...
const pixelBuffer = new Uint8Array(4 * w * h);
renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(renderTarget, 0, 0, w, h, pixelBuffer);
for (let y = 0, offset = 0; y < h; ++y) {
    for (let x = 0; x < w; ++x, offset += 4) {

         // does pixel correspond to overhang area?
         if (pixelBuffer[offset + 3] > 0) {
             const posX = 2 * pixelBuffer[offset] / 255 - 1;
             const posY = 2 * pixelBuffer[offset + 1] / 255 - 1;
             const posZ = 2 * pixelBuffer[offset + 2] / 255 - 1;
             // ...
         }
    }
}
```

However, 8 bit precision may be not enough for your purposes. In that case, you can use `FLOAT` or `HALF_FLOAT` render targets (if a browser supports them).

You may also try GPGPU approach. Basically, most of the time its using fragment shaders to compute some value(s), which then would be stored in a texture (usually, `FLOAT` or `HALF_FLOAT` too) and either read back to CPU or sampled in subsequent drawing to use computed values. There's a lot of information about GPGPU in WebGL, e.g. [this](http://www.lab4games.net/zz85/blog/2014/02/17/webgl-gpgpu-flocking-birds-part-ii-shaders/).

Regarding transform feedback. Yes, it's specifically used to store results of a vertex shader in some buffer, which again can be read back to CPU (rarely) or reused on GPU, for example as an input for another or even the same vertex shader. But TF's available only in WebGL 2.

Comment: Webgl 2.0 is not a problem as its now supported in all major browsers , how would i go about urilising transform feedback and reading vertex positions from it? Basically what i want to do is output the overhang vertices (x,y,z) cordinates from the vertex shader to the program and generate recursive fractal trees from the ground to those points ... i cant go with te pixels approach because i would process only the visible pixels i think , so transform feedback is the only option , i looked at a three js sample using transform feedback but cant figure out how to read the values from it...

Comment: You can just read from WebGL buffer TF writes to (the one bound to `TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFER`) with [`getBufferSubData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext/getBufferSubData) function (sadly, Three.js doesn't seem to use it in any way, so you'll need to hack it a little bit, or find a plugin or something). However, it may not be somewhat suboptimal, since reading back from GPU is always expensive. If you have dataset of moderate size, workers may be a better solution. Also note that TF won't allow you to generate **new** vertices. It's like array's `map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use other an FBO or transform feedback. With transform feedbackhe only problem is AFAICT  there is no way to discard vertices so like you mentioned the best you can do in that case is write some special value for non-overlapping vertices.

To use an FBO you make a floating point texture and check you can render to it. In WebGL1 that means enabling floating point textures, binding one to a framebuffer and calling checkFramebufferStatus. In WebGL 2 it means checking for and enabling `EXT_color_buffer_float` (and still calling checkFramebufferStatus)

You then make a buffer with just a count [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc.] use that to generate a `gl_Position` that will write to the next pixel in the FBO.

```
// WebGL2 
varying uint count; 
uniform uint2 resolutionOfFBO;

// compute output pixel
uint x = count % resolutinOfFBO.x;
uint y = count / resolutionOfFBO.x;

// set gl_Position so we'll write to that output pixel
gl_Position = vec4((vec2(x, y) + .5) / resolutionOfFBO, 0, 1);
```

Pass the data you want to write in a varying and write that data in the fragment shader. Then render with `POINTS`.

You can then read the data back with `gl.readPixels`

Explaining transform feedback seems a little long for this question but here's a simple example: The input is `[1, 2, 3]` and the output is `[2, 4, 6]`

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl2");
  
  const vs = `#version 300 es
    in float in_value;
    out float out_value;
    
    void main() {
       out_value = in_value * 2.;
    }
  `;
  const fs = `#version 300 es
    precision mediump float;
    layout (location = 0) out vec4 dummy;
    void main() {
      dummy = vec4(1);
    }
  `;
  const prog = createProgram(gl, [vs, fs], ["out_value"]);
  const inLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(prog, 'in_value');
  const outLoc = 0;  
  
  const numVaryings = gl.getProgramParameter(prog, gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_VARYINGS);

  const srcBuffer1 = createBuffer(gl, new Float32Array([1, 2, 3]));
  const srcVAO1 = createVAO(gl, srcBuffer1, inLoc);

  const dstBuffer = createBuffer(gl, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 3);
  const srcVAO2 = createVAO(gl, dstBuffer, inLoc);

  const tf = gl.createTransformFeedback();
  gl.bindTransformFeedback(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, tf);
  gl.useProgram(prog);
  gl.bindBufferBase(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, dstBuffer);
  // this binds the default (id = 0) TRANSFORM_FEEBACK buffer
  gl.bindTransformFeedback(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, null);
  // This line is onky because of a bug in Chrome
  gl.bindBufferBase(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, null);

  runFeedback(gl, prog, srcVAO1, tf);  
  checkGLError(gl);
  
  const result = new Float32Array(3);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, dstBuffer);
  gl.getBufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, result);
  log(result);
}
main();

function runFeedback(gl, prog, srcVAO, tf, dstBufferInfo) {
  gl.enable(gl.RASTERIZER_DISCARD);

  gl.useProgram(prog);
  gl.bindVertexArray(srcVAO);
  
  gl.bindTransformFeedback(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, tf);
  gl.beginTransformFeedback(gl.TRIANGLES);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  gl.endTransformFeedback();
  
  gl.bindTransformFeedback(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, null);

  gl.disable(gl.RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
}

function checkGLError(gl) {
  const err = gl.getError();
  if (err) {
    log("GL ERROR:", err);
  }
}

function createShader(gl, shaderSource, shaderType) {
  var shader = gl.createShader(shaderType);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  var compiled = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (!compiled) {
    console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
    return null;
  }
  return shader;
}

function createProgram(gl, shaderSources, outputs) {
  const shaderTypes = [gl.VERTEX_SHADER, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER];
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  shaderSources.forEach(function(shaderSrc, ndx) {
    gl.attachShader(program, createShader(gl, shaderSrc, shaderTypes[ndx]));
  });
  
  if (outputs) {
    gl.transformFeedbackVaryings(program, outputs, gl.SEPARATE_ATTRIBS);
  }
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  var linked = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if (!linked) {
    console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    gl.deleteProgram(program);
    return null;
  }
  return program;
}
 
function createBuffer(gl, dataOrSize) {
  const buf = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, dataOrSize, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  return buf;
}

function createVAO(gl, buf, inLoc) {
  const vao = gl.createVertexArray();
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(inLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(inLoc, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);  // this is not needed
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);
  return vao;
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement("pre");
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

The short explanation is with transform feedbacks your output varyings from your vertex shader are written to one or more buffers.

To do that you have to tell your shader program at link time what your outputs are with `gl.transformFeedbackVaryings`.

Then you create a transform feedback object. A transform feedback object is very similar to a vertex array object except it's for outputs instead of inputs. You specify the outputs by calling `gl.bindBufferBase` for each output just like you'd call `gl.vertexAttribPointer` for each input on vertex array object.

To actually generate the output you probably want to tell WebGL not to run the fragment shader

```
gl.enable(gl.RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
```

Then you bind your transform feedback object, turn on transform feedback and draw

```
gl.bindTransformFeedback(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, tf);
gl.beginTransformFeedback(gl.TRIANGLES);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
gl.endTransformFeedback();
```

When you link the program you can choose separate or interleaved attribtes. With separate each attribute can go to a different buffer but there's a limit on how many attributes you can write (min is at least 4). With interleaved all outputs get written but they are interleaved. For example if you were writing both positions and normals then the output would be

```
position0, normal0, position1, normal1, position2, normal2
```

all to the same buffer.